# Creating template handler in PHP (negative look ahead problem)

Tags: php, regex, template-engine

I'm developing a little template handler in PHP like smarty just a much simpler one. I used smarty before but it was too robust for me. I thought that I'm ready with my one but a really annoying bug showed up.
My conception is simple. I use preg_split to separate the template commands and the html code, process and implode. the {foreach} command works just fine so I won't mantion it at all, the bug appears in the {if} clause.
The "{if} part" of the regexp is:

```
{if\s+[a-zA-Z0-9\{'\}\=\s\/$\!\=]{1,}\s*}
```

The problem is that I have to allow curly brackets because of the variable substitution and that causes the regexp not to stop at the end of the "{if****}". I tried negative look aheads and negate positive look aheads to exclude "{if" to avoid the problem but I had no luck.

An example for the template:

```
{if '{$a}' = 'a'}
    blabla
    {if 'c' = 'c'}
        blabla
    {/if}
{/if}
valami más
{if 'b' != 'b'}
    blabla
{/if}
{if '{$c}' = '{$c}'}
    blabla
{/if}
```

Output expected:

```
{if '{$a}' = 'a'}
{if 'c' = 'c'}
{if 'b' != 'b'}
{if '{$c}' = '{$c}'}
```

Could somebody please help?

Comment: If you are doing this for yourself, then don't bother, I recommend you PIP, it's just tiny and great http://gilbitron.github.com/PIP/ .

Comment: off topic, you are just reinvent the wheel where there are so many php template engine available for FREE!!!

Comment: This may sound pedantic, but PHP itself is a templating engine. Why add another one on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description above, I've created the following regex.  I hope this is what you're looking for.

```
<?php

$string = <<<'EOD'
{if '{$a}' = 'a'}
blabla
{if 'c' = 'c'}
    blabla
{/if}
{/if}
valami más
{if 'b' != 'b'}
blabla
{/if}
{if '{$c}' = '{$c}'}
blabla
{/if}
EOD;

$pattern = "~{if\s+'(?:\\{\\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\})|(?:[A-Za-z0-9]))'\s+(?:=|(?:!=))\s+'(?:(?:\\{\\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\}))|(?:[A-Za-z0-9]))'\\}~";

preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches,1).'</pre>';

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {if '{$a}' = 'a'}
        [1] => {if 'c' = 'c'}
        [2] => {if 'b' != 'b'}
        [3] => {if '{$c}' = '{$c}'}
    )
```

)

**Updated Answer**

With the below comments in mind, I have created the following regex.  I admit it is by far not the best solution, but it works to allow for arguments such as `{if '{$c}' = '{$c}' && '{$b}' = '{$b}'}`.  You could simply duplicate the pattern to allow for more than two expressions in a single `if` statement.  Obviously, it would then grow to a ridiculous length!  If this is for a templating engine, however, perhaps it would not need much extending?  Any other operators required can also simply be added into the regex at the appropriate place.

Once again, I am aware this isn't the best way of solving the problem; I'm sorry I can't create a recursive version myself.  Perhaps someone else will be able to do so!

```
$pattern = "~{if\s+(?:(?:'(?:\\{\\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\})|(?:[A-Za-z0-9]))'\s+(?:=|(?:!=)|(?:==)|(?:<=)|(?:>=))\s+'(?:(?:\\{\\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\}))|(?:[A-Za-z0-9]))')(?:(?:\s+(?:&&|\\|\\|)\s+)(?:'(?:\\{\\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\})|(?:[A-Za-z0-9]))'\s+(?:=|(?:!=)|(?:==)|(?:<=)|(?:>=))\s+'(?:(?:\\{\\$(?:[A-Za-z0-9]+\\}))|(?:[A-Za-z0-9]))'))?)\\}~";
```

Tested on:

```
$string = <<<'EOD'
{if '{$a}' = 'a'}
blabla
{if 'c' = 'c'}
blabla
{/if}
{/if}
valami más
{if 'b' != 'b'}
blabla
{/if}
{if '{$c}' = '{$c}'}
blabla
{/if}
{if '{$c}' = '{$c}' && '{$b}' = '{$b}'}
EOD;
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => {if '{$a}' = 'a'}
        [1] => {if 'c' = 'c'}
        [2] => {if 'b' != 'b'}
        [3] => {if '{$c}' = '{$c}'}
        [4] => {if '{$c}' = '{$c}' && '{$b}' = '{$b}'}
    )
)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. It's not a bad solution but what I didn't write at first time is that I don't only want '==' and '!=' operators to work but every other, so "&&" and "||" and "<=" .... I give the inner content to the php's eval function and it would be great if it could evaluate every kind of logical things. For example "{if '{$a}' == 'a' || '{$a}' == 'b'}" should work as well.

Comment: I shall suggest an amended regex, which will be rather long-winded, but it seems to do the job.  I'll update my answer with it in a second.  I'd be keen to see how other people solve the problem though; I think a recursive call is needed here, but I haven't been able to get that work, since I'm not all that with regex!

Comment: Thank you for the answer again. I always stand for perfection but I think your solution can handle the 99 percent of the cases. I would appreciate other solutions though. I think I will wait a week and if there is no other solution then you will be victorious :)